# Redis Vs. Web service for Push Notifications in iOS Application

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, mobile, redis

I am exploring Redis and I wanted to know which one among Redis and Web Services, will be better, more fast and compatible to use for a Social Networking iOS Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, Redis is not secure enough to be connected to mobile devices through the Internet. Its security mechanism is only meant to protect against user mistakes rather than from attacks.

It is supposed to be used on a trusted network only, behind an application back-end. So it is probably not a good choice to fan out notifications directly to mobile devices.

Comment: Okay, so you suggest that its better to use WebServices for Security reasons?

Comment: Redis is a distributed store. WebServices is a communication mechanism - they should not be considered as similar things in your architecture. If you want to use Redis for your use case, consider putting a back-end between Redis and the Internet.